# Convert JSON.Stringify to Number error

Tags: json, node.js

```
var id = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N); //returns a number as a string like "42"

var id = Number(JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N)); //returns NaN
```

I've tried parseInt, parseFloat, etc but I'm not sure why I can't parse the string returned from Stringify into a number. How should I convert?

Comment: *"returns a number as a string like "42""* Are the double quotes part of the string value? If yes that's the problem. And that means that `record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N` is a string already. Why are you calling `JSON.stringify` at all? Which problem are you trying to solve here?If `record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N` is a string already then you only need `Number(record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N)`.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up for me. I feel silly. The dynamoDB syntax is new to me and I assumed that record.dynamodb.NewImage.id.N was a number because of the 'N' (string is S). But the call to record.dynamodb is just a query for 'id' which is a number ('N'). The actual return is a string not a number. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `JSON.stringify` is adding another pair of `""` to your id, cause its already a string. Take the `JSON.stringify` away and it should work just fine. Or if you need to parse the JSON string into a JSON first use `JSON.parse()` and then parse the ID property into an Int.

Answer (score 0):

`var num = Number(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('42')));`

You have to first use `JSON.parse` first then convent it in to Number

Comment: Why you use `JSON.stringify` then the first place then?